# Docusign template fields not appearing? It's just blank

Tags: php, api, docusignapi, crm

I have the API built in my custom CRM and its working fine but the issue is that the application is being sent out blank. We currently have it on the docusign console were we already have the necessary fields that will guide the client through the process instead of them having to drag and drop certain items.

Here is a text link of how it's being sent, which is wrong:

[image]

Here's how it should appear:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's likely that the Roles listed in the Template don't match what's being defined in your API call. You'll want to check how your template is set up and make sure both Role Name and Routing Order match exactly in your API call.